# javax.mail is not exist in the java develop with the maven

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail

the jdk is the 1.8 and the maven is 3.6 and the idea is 2020
when i user the javax.mail 1.4
it prompt the package javax.mail is not exist
but i can find the package in my maven localRepositroy

how to deal with it,

Comment: Is the IDE or maven mentioning the problem? Do you run maven from the IDE or Terminal / Command line?

Comment: Apart from the questions... you should upgrade the whole area IDE, JDK, Maven ....